# How to force DB transaction with Spring Hibernate & Repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot (quite a newbie) with Hibernate & CrudRepository I'm trying to use an actual transaction in my MySQL DB to force blocking (I'm required to allow only a single request to perform a specific operation across my service and my strategy is to lock some object in the DB and by that to synchronize all of my servers).

Using the @Transactional and even @EnableTransactionManagement create a logical transaction without committing until success, however it doesn't create a DB transaction thus other requests are able to modify the same record and continue. How can I create such transaction?

Code examples:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "locks")
public class Lock {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "locked_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lockedAt = null;
}

@EnableTransactionManagement
@Transactional
public interface LockDao extends CrudRepository<Lock, Integer> {
}

public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private final LockDao lockDao;

    @Transactional
    public void doSomething() {
        Lock lock = new Lock();
        lock.setId(1);
        lock.setLockedAt(new Date());
        lockDao.save(lock);

        // Do something 
    }
}
```

Comment: Transaction in spring framework is thread bounded within an application server. If you have multiple application servers that share the same databases you need a synchronization on distributed transaction.

Comment: I believe we agree and this is exactly what I'm looking for - how to start a DB transaction

Comment: `@EnableTransactionManagement` needs to be on a `@Configuration` class not some other random other class. The `CrudRepository` is transactional by default and what should be transactional is your service not your dao. In short move the `@EnableTransactionManagement` to a `@Configuration` class.

Comment: Well, I found out that basically it issued the correct SQLs even without `@EnableTransactionManagement`, however the problem was that it didn't flush it - so actually other requests coming in could also set the lock and were not blocked by a transaction. So my problem was how to flush in this specific method - I found a way doing that by `@Autowired`-ing `EntityManager` and calling its `flush` method - however, is that a "valid" spring-boot & hibernate solution?